# How to align side-bar with youtube player in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created simple web page using html5,css and js.

I have created side-bar first one section is login form and another one is video player.

This is code in html5 for both:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
<div class="inside">
<section id="content">
        <form action="">
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="username" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" />

            </div>
        </form><!-- form -->

    </section><!-- content --></div>
</aside>
<aside class="sidebar">
  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
      poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    <track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
    <track kind="subtitles" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
  </video>
  </aside>
```

And this is css:

```
/* aside */
aside {
float: left;
max-width: 100px;
margin-top:320px;
height: 200px;
}
.inside {
background-color: #000;
color:#fff;
position:relative;
}
.sidebar.sticky {
float: none;
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
z-index: 6;
left: auto;
}
```

Now my page looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/mrse2fyep/

I want to display video player bottom of login form. but it shows near by the login form.

May i know what is the css to fix it.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not see any login form in the page provided [here](http://postimg.org/image/mrse2fyep/).

Comment: @Cyzanfar, it's behind the video, at the left.

Comment: please see  this http://imgur.com/U1dollN @Cyzanfar

Comment: something like [link](http://jsfiddle.net/odg041s5/)

Comment: if both the contents are floating then try changing the width of login form. also you may want to override `max-width: 100px`

Comment: remove float:left from aside and change margin-top

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `float` value from the `aside` which contains the video. I've added another class to the `aside` like this:

```
<aside class="sidebar video-content">
```

And the css:

```
.video-content {
    float: none;
}
```

[See my fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/g214r3hb/)